# How to run custom script in razzle?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, babeljs

I have react/node project setup in using razzle. Now I want to run a custom script that will do some db operations, which will require some modules from src directory.

My question is do I need to setup babel separately for this(as the modules are in es6/es7), or can I use the existing setup from razzle? Pardon me if this seems too obvious.